# elementary OS has the MATE DE

Tags: release-loki, ubuntu, desktop-environment

I have two users on my PC, one desktop environment looks similar to a standard eOS except the icons are MATE-like and some icons are missing.

The other user's desktop environment looks like MATE:
[image: System:About MAte]

Output of lsb_release -a 
[image: Terminal window]

I have tried updating and re-installing the desktop with no luck.

All help appreciated.

Maybe unrelated info:
I am running Windows 10 and elementary OS dual-boot to try escape the windows jail, I have managed not to boot into windows for over three months and am very happy with eOS and have installed it on my kids PC's as their default OS. Runs very well and all the hardware/dongles etc work just fine.

Disclaimer: I am a NOOB

Answer (score 1):

My eOS desktop was ruined by installing a GNOME screensaver.

Re-installed eOS and problem solved.